# Group rows by 7 days interval starting from a certain date

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to group rows by a 7 days intervals(datetime) starting from a certain date in Mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Group by Week Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492187/mysql-group-by-week-question)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    1 + DATEDIFF(columnDate, @start_date) DIV 7  AS weekNumber
  , @start_date + INTERVAL (DATEDIFF(columnDate, @start_date) DIV 7) WEEK
      AS week_start_date
  , MIN(columnDate) AS actual_first_date
  , MAX(columnDate) AS actual_last_date
  , SUM(otherColumn)
  , AVG(otherColumn)
  --- 
FROM 
    tableX 
WHERE 
    columnDate >= @start_date 
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(columnDate, @start_date) DIV 7 ;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I'm not quite confortable with date processing in Mysql but it seems that it's not so hard. Thank you!

Comment: Does this require a row for every day?

Comment: @AndrewTibbetts what do you mean?

Comment: Does there need to be a row with a date for every day within the week for the datediff to work? In other words, does the `DIV 7` in the `GROUP BY` require 7 rows?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ awesome answerdude.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Do you have a way this can be done in sQL Server. I was looking to implement the same on SQL Server. Need to group on 7 days intervals.

Comment: @KashyapMNVL you could use `GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day, @start_date, columnDate) / 7`.

Comment: Or just `GROUP BY DATEDIFF(week, @start_date, columnDate)`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: When I do that, I get the following error message on SSMS.
"Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."
Any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM  `table` 
GROUP BY WEEK( ADDDATE( `date_column` , WEEKDAY(NOW()) ) )
```

Comment: it's pretty close, but this gives me the weeks starting with Sunday or Monday. I need the starting day to be the weekday of the given date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.* from users 
WHERE created_at >= '2011-12-01' 
AND created_at <= date_add('2011-12-01', INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

This selects the users created between 201-12-01 and 7 days after that.
Make changes, to query based on your need.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer! But this gives me only the first 7 day interval. I need all 7 day intervals starting from that date.