# Mysql query group by week with specific start and end

Tags: mysql

I searched stack overflow and have come so close yet have not found if this is possible.

I want to group a weekly query  from 11:30 am Friday to 11:29 am Friday for each week.

adding days and hours only partially work. I need to keep this in a mysql query not coding in php, etc.

Comment: I think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492187/mysql-group-by-week-question?rq=1 will give you most of what you're looking for. If you show the research that you've done so far as well as what you've tried that has or hasn't worked, you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information on your table structure and some sample date. If I have understood correctly then below is simple pseudo code  which you can start use to start framing your requirement .

```
select something from table where date between 1:30 am Friday and 11:29 am
group by trunc(date).
```

Note : 
- Format the date in where condition using to_Date.
- Week definition might be different in database so you need to manipulate.

Comment: This get me close but I need to get the time in here some how.

select
    count(OrderIdNumber) as cnt,
    CASE WHEN (weekday(DateOfRecord)<=4) THEN date(DateOfRecord + INTERVAL (4-weekday(DateOfRecord)) DAY)
        ELSE date(DateOfRecord + INTERVAL (4+7-weekday(DateOfRecord)) DAY)
    END as dt
FROM convertdollarwithoutcancel
WHERE DateOfRecord between '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY DateOfRecord

Comment: If i use this i get the correct number of orders. 
.

select count(OrderIdNumber)from convertdollarwithoutcancel Where DateOfRecord >=  '2016-01-01 11:33:00' and DateOfRecord <= '2016-01-08 11:32:00'

Comment: Sorry, It seems really stupid but nothing I try will let me format the comment.